# Swift2 not performing segue when login

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2

I'm trying to do an uber clone app to improve myself. I successfully made the login and signup page and created a new `viewController` for when riders log in.

But the problem is my segue is not performing when I call it. I get the `"success"` printed in logs but the segue is not performing at all.

My code:

```
if user != nil {               
    // Login Succesfull                  
    print("Success")
    if let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser() {
        if currentUser["type"] as! String == "rider" {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("riderLogInSegue", sender: self)
        }
    }                        
}
```

My storyboard and segue:

[image]

whole error is:

2016-06-16 19:34:49.783 ParseStarterProject-Swift[3464:224536] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle  (loaded)' with name 'UIViewController-BYZ-38-t0r' and directory 'Main.storyboardc''

Comment: try to put break point and check whether  `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("riderLogInSegue", sender: self)` is executing or not.

Comment: I tried to add one more print("success") just before performSegue method in the if statement, and it also logged in success correctly.

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: Override 'prepareforsegue' segue method and check whether it is called or not.

Comment: I tried to put breakpoint and it stopped in self.performSegueWithIdentifier("riderLogInSegue", sender: self) with green mark. I dont know how breakpoints work well so i have no idea about it. Also about prepareforsegue, i tried it and it didnt called

Comment: Can you show your storyboard with segue selected.

Comment: I added my screenshot to main post

Comment: Have you try my answer.